# NHibernate paging with SQL Server

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2000, paging

When using `SetFirstResult(start)` and `SetMaxResults(count)` methods to implement paging I've noticed that the generated query only does a `select top count * from some_table` and it does not take the `start` parameter into account or at least not at the database level. It seems that if I instruct NHibernate to execute the following query:

```
var users = session.CreateCriteria<User>()
                   .SetFirstResult(100)
                   .SetMaxResults(5)
                   .List<User>();
```

105 records will transit between the database server and the application which will take care to strip the first 100 records. With tables containing many rows this could be a problem.

I've verified that with an [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) database NHibernate takes advantage of the `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` keywords to filter results at the database level. I am aware that there's no equivalent of the `OFFSET` keyword and Oracle's `ROWNUM` in SQL Server 2000 but is there any workaround? How about SQL Server 2005/2008?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

T-SQL, the variant of the SQL language which Microsoft SQL Server uses, does not have a `limit` clause. It has a `select top {...}` modifier which you see NHibernate taking advantage of with SQL Server 2000.

With SQL Server 2005, Microsoft introduced the `Row_Number() over (order by {...})` function which can be used as a replacement to the `limit` clause, and you can see NHibernate taking advantage of that with SQL Server 2005/2008.

A query for SQLite might look like

```
select c.[ID], c.[Name]
from [Codes] c
where c.[Key] = 'abcdef'
order by c.[Order]
limit 20 offset 40
```

while a similar query for SQL Server 2005 might look like

```
select c.[ID], c.[Name]
from (
    select c.[ID], c.[Name], c.[Order]
        , [!RowNum] = Row_Number() over (order by c.[Order])
    from [Codes] c
    where c.[Key] = 'abcdef'
) c
where c.[!RowNum] > 40 and c.[!RowNum] <= 60
order by c.[Order]
```

or, using Common Table Expressions, it might look like

```
with
    [Source] as (
        select c.[ID], c.[Name], c.[Order]
            , [!RowNum] = Row_Number() over (order by c.[Order])
        from [Codes] c
        where c.[Key] = 'abcdef'
    )
select c.[ID], c.[Name]
from [Source] c
where c.[!RowNum] > 40 and c.[!RowNum] <= 60
order by c.[Order]
```

There is a way to do it in SQL Server 2000 as well

```
select c.[ID], c.[Name]
from (
    select top 20 c.[ID], c.[Name], c.[Order]
    from (
        select top 60 c.[ID], c.[Name], c.[Order]
        from [Codes] c
        where c.[Key] = 'abcdef'
        order by c.[Order]
    ) c
    order by c.[Order] desc
) c
order by c.[Order]
```

Answer (score 5):

Nhibernate is smart enough to optimize query. If you select first 10 rows it will use `TOP` statement. If you select not first rows then it will use `RowNum`.

In sql 2000 there is no `RowNum` function, that's why it is impossible with usual query to select required number of rows. For sql 2000 as I know for such an optimization views were used.

In sql 2005/2008 query will select only required rows.

---

Comment: I've verified that with sql 2005/2008 NHibernate uses the `row_number()` function. It seems that with sql 2000 I have to write views or stored procedures to achieve the same effect.